Newly created angular project has errors
for some unknown reason a freshly generated angular 14.1 project does not work. it seems like npm i  will download corrupt libs. deleting node_modules won't help.. the file (node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts) in my existing projects looks differently.. i wasn't able to find anything similar on the internet... any idea? thanks!
Error: node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:484:13 - error TS2502: 'ReadableByteStreamController' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

484         var ReadableByteStreamController: typeof globalThis extends
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:503:13 - error TS2502: 'ReadableStreamBYOBReader' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

503         var ReadableStreamBYOBReader: typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any; ReadableStreamBYOBReader: infer T }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@types/node/stream/web.d.ts:513:13 - error TS2502: 'ReadableStreamBYOBRequest' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

513         var ReadableStreamBYOBRequest: typeof globalThis extends { onmessage: any; ReadableStreamBYOBRequest: infer T }
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Downgrade @types/node, recent versions dropped support for older TypeScript versions

Do you have compatible NodeJS version?

I don't want to pry as for your reasons to use Angular 14, but do note that support for older Angular versions has already been dropped, meaning you should consider using a newer (or the newest) version for your new project!

I had the same issue with my CI pipeline. after installing npm i -D @types/node@latest
solved my issue.

thanks! i upgraded to the latest version now. i still have however some legacy projects...

I had the same issue and just solved it in the following way.
Set the skipLibCheck flag to true in the angularCompilerOptions inside your tsconfig.json file.
{
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

This tells TypeScript to skip type checking for third-party libraries, which can help avoid circular reference issues.

it misup the routing feature

Downgrade "@types/node" in devDependencies of package.json. "ng new" puts the latest version for this dependency which has breaking changes for a few older features.
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/node": "^20.3.2",
    ...
  }


let's add that this should ideally contain the version number of the Node that actually runs the project. In the case of Angular 14, this should be ~14 or ~16.

In my case i was able to solve it because i had the package-lock.json of the project that i just cloned, if you have it you could use npm ci instead of npm install to make sure you have all the dependencies as before

This implies that there is something wrong with the package-lock.json of a freshly generated angular 14 project.

Today I learned, that even with unchanged package-lock.json it can be compiled successfully with npm ci after fixing the dependencies in package.json as explained in my answer.

Based on Angular version compatibility table we should use Node

^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0

For Angular

14.0.x || 14.1.x
14.2.x || 14.3.x

BUT as of this writing, a freshly generated angular 14 project (optionally) depends on Node 22.10.2 (or @types/node)
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/node": "^16.10.0",
    ...
}

Finally, run npm install to omit optional dependencies in packages-lock.json.

Try change angular version. Of course, the best solution would be to use the latest stable version (~18.2.1) if there is no reason to work with such an old one.
