ASP.NET Core Development Certificates - error exporting the HTTPS developer certificate
I installed Visual Studio 2022 on my laptop, which is a Windows 11 Home Edition.
I created a new Angular and ASP.NET Core web application, using all the defaults.
When Visual Studio was creating the solution, and again every time I try to run it using the F5 key, I get this error, in a command window:
First command: > angularapp1.client@0.0.0 prestart
Second command: > node aspnetcore-https
Error:
There was an error exporting the HTTPS developer certificate to a file.
This is a fresh install of Visual Studio 2022, and the solution was created using all the defaults, which works perfectly on my Windows 10 PC.
It happens even when I run VS as Administrator.
I have tried running these commands:
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
But that did not help.
Then I tried running this command:
dotnet dev-certs https -ep %USERPROFILE%.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p MyPassword
But it said that a valid HTTPS certificate was already present.
I ran this:
dotnet dev-certs https -v
And it found only one valid certificate.
I tried creating a second Angular and ASP.NET Core web application, but got the same error.
I don't know what else to try.
Can anyone help?

check to be sure folder exists... it should be something like c:\users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https  If not, create it.

According to this link, there is a bug in new versions of .NET where the certificate folder is not automatically created.
The workaround is to add the following code in the aspnetcore-https.js file:
    const fs = require('fs');
    //...
    const baseFolder = 
    //...
    fs.mkdirSync(baseFolder, { recursive: true });



This solved the problem for me also.
However, I then immediately ran into another issue, which has solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78951554/newly-created-angular-project-has-errors
I am working with a legacy solution, which cannot be upgraded for various  reasons, so what worked for me was:
{
"angularCompilerOptions": {
"skipLibCheck": true
}
}

This additional line also worked in macOS when loading an existing Angular/C#.NET Core project for the first time. Nice!

just added fs.mkdirSync(baseFolder, { recursive: true }); and it worked bcs first to lines are already there

I fixed the issue running Visual Studio as Administrator
